# Nestjs Yarn build failed Error: Cannot find module './_assignValue'

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I tried to start a new project using nestjs and yarn after I run yarn install which is compeleted successfully I run yarn build and here is what I got

The Error :

```
$ rimraf dist
$ nest build
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
throw err;
     ^

Error: Cannot find module './_assignValue'
Require stack:
- /home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/lodash/_copyObject.js
- /home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/lodash/assignIn.js
- /home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/lodash/extend.js
- /home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/baseUI.js
- /home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/bottom-bar.js
- /home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js
- /home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/lib/utils/project-utils.js
- /home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/actions/generate.action.js   
- /home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/actions/index.js
- /home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands/command.loader.js
- /home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands/index.js
- /home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/lodash/_copyObject.js:1:19)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
  '/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/lodash/_copyObject.js',
  '/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/lodash/assignIn.js',
  '/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/lodash/extend.js',
  '/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/baseUI.js',
  '/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/bottom-bar.js',
  '/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js',
  '/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/lib/utils/project-utils.js',
  '/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/actions/generate.action.js',
  '/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/actions/index.js',
  '/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands/command.loader.js',
  '/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands/index.js',
  '/home/ashraf/test-project/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js'
]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

In other hand if I tried using `npm install` and `npm run build` everything works fine !